# Modify standard redirect url after session time out

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, session, redirect

How can I modify the standard url after session time out?
'http://www.domain.com/component/users/?view=login'

The loginform module for my frontend is deactivated. Instead there is a custom login form (with a custom login procedure).

Everything works fine except the problem, that Joomla redirects after session time out to its standard login url.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a template override for the login template being called when the standard login url is displayed. There you create a `HTTP 302 Move` response status.

Or you write a url rewrite to your `.htaccess`.

Both solutions could get you where you wanna be, but I would consider them 'dirty'.